# Cordova aap can be developed on visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

Can we develop `cordova/phonegap` app on `Visual Studio version 2012`? I am beginner, any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could develop a Cordova app using Visual Studio 2012 inside of a WebSite project (for example). However, it's not a great experience. Visual Studio 2015 includes official support for Apache Cordova (see more at http://taco.visualstudio.com). You may be able to use the free Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.